# Why does my UIView got different position on different iPhones?

Tags: swift, autolayout, autoresizingmask

Why does my `UIView` got different position on different iPhone screen sizes ? I guess it's because of `autoresizingMask` but how could I get a frame of a view after applying `autoresizingMask`, to create some universal logic? or whats the best practice to handle this ?

here is the code :

```
private func setup() {

        positionView = CircularProjectPositionControl(frame: self.bounds)
        positionView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        positionView.outerCircleWidth = outerCircleWidth

        assetsView = CircularProjectAssetsControl(frame: self.bounds)
        assetsView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        assetsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        assetsView.imageWidth = outerCircleWidth

        let size = CGSize(width:40, height:40)
        let width = floor(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - size.width/2.0)
        let height = floor(CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - size.width/2.0)
        collaboratorView = AvatarView(frame: CGRect(x: width, y: height, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        collaboratorView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleBottomMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleRightMargin]

        self.addSubview(assetsView)
        self.addSubview(positionView)
        self.addSubview(collaboratorView)
    }
```

iPhone 6s: 
[image]

iPhone 5:
[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this programmatically? It will be much easier using auto layout constraints in Storyboard

Comment: @matt.writes.code I cant use storyboard here

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.CenterX` & `.CenterY` contraints to center each of the subviews:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only set the relative position with the self.view. If you want three circles have some remain same relative position with each other, you should also set the constraint between them.

Comment: so should i add an auto layout constraints or a autoresizingMask mask ?